# Elastic Bean Stalk: Updating load balancer named: awseb-e-w-AWSEBLoa-xxxxx failed Reason: ELB cannot be attached to multiple subnets in the same AZ

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I'm trying to get HTTPS connection for my ElasticBeanStalk environment, to accomplish this I'm following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html, which implicates setting up a load balancer, when I configure the load balancer in the environment settings, the deploy fails with

```
"Updating load balancer named: awseb-e-w-AWSEBLoa-xxxxx failed Reason: ELB cannot be attached to multiple subnets in the same AZ. (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 409; Error Code: InvalidConfigurationRequest; Request ID: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx; Proxy: null)
"
```

I managed to get around this by unchecking some subnets in ElasticBeanStalk networks config. But when i do so the EC2 instance become unresponsive and can't even SSH to it and the environment get stuck on "No Data". It return responsive if i remove the load balancer.

How can i configure my subnets properly so that everything works? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the subnets you are selecting for the load balancer in a public subnet?

Comment: I have 4 subnets that looks like this:

1- ea-west1a public
2- ea-west1a private

3- ea-west1b public
4- ea-west1b private

if I check all the subnets and try to deploy, I get the error, instead when i try to check only few of them,
e.g. (ea-west1a public + ea-west1a private) or (ea-west1a public + ea-west1b private) environment deploy successfully but in "No data" state (not actually working)

Comment: You need to check public subnets only for the load balancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by doing this:

After requesting a certificate in [AWS Certificate Manager](https://console.aws.amazon.com/acm/home)

-Go to your environment configuration and choose "Load Balancer" (You may have to Change "Capacity" from "Single instance" to "Load Balanced" first )

- Next choose "Add listener" and set it up like this

PORT 443

Protocol HTTPS

Choose the SSL Certificate you requested in ACM

SSL Policy is optional

Done.

Now open [Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) and in "Hosted Zones" write your domain and point it to the Elastic Bean Stalk environment URI, this domain will now have HTTPS

You may need to prepend https:// manually to the URL for the domain using the certificate, sometimes further configuration is needed for auto redirection.

(Note that the elasticbeanstalk.com domain still  won't have HTTPS)